# What does " &, " " mean in MS Access?

Tags: ms-access

I am having trouble understanding the point of the following,  say we have thestatement

x- autonumber, Primary Key
 State – Text(255), Required: Yes, Allow zero length: No (not allowing dirty nulls)

Country – Required: Yes, lookup in COUNTRIES:

```
SELECT x, Country FROM COUNTRIES ORDER BY Country;
```

StateCode – Text (8), Allow zero length: NO

StateTelPrefix – integer, Validation rule: between 0 and 500
StateCapital - Required: No, lookup in CITIES:

```
SELECT CITIES.x, [City] & ", " & [STATES].[State]
& ", " & [COUNTRIES].[Country]
AS [City, State, Country]
FROM COUNTRIES INNER JOIN (STATES INNER JOIN CITIES
ON STATES.x = CITIES.State)
ON COUNTRIES.x = STATES.Country
ORDER BY [City] & ", " & [STATES].[State] & ", " &
[COUNTRIES].[Country];
```

what's the point of this part:

```
 & ", " &
```

Comment: That query is *not* (standard) SQL

Comment: I shall add more info with a longer statement maybe someone will get it, its has puzzled me

Answer (score 2):

Quoting [Joining two strings of text together in Access](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/joining-two-strings-of-text-together-in-access-HA001054726.aspx)

> You can join two strings of text together by using the `&` operator in an expression. This is called concatenation.

Or better from [Table of operators](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/access-help/table-of-operators-HA010235862.aspx#_Toc272228351)

> ***`&`*** Combines two strings to form one string.     `string1 & string2`

---

In your specific case it concatenates to a single string the values of 3 columns (*city, state and country*) and adds a comma and space between each..

```
[City] & ", " & [STATES].[State] & ", " & [COUNTRIES].[Country]
```

will result in something like ***Dallas, Texas, USA***